# how to click button till there is no such element?

Tags: robotframework

I have test case to delete files one by one, i want it to click each file till there is no file.

but actual execution just delete one file and stopped.

is that i need to implement for loop?

please advise how to do it in robot.

```
Delete All Files
    Wait Until Page Contains And Click              ${SETTINGS-FILES}
    ${FILES}   Run Keyword And Return Status    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${ANDROID-WIDGET-LISTVIEW}\[@resource-id="FilesList"]  2s
    Run Keyword If    ${FILES}      Wait Until Page Contains And Click              ${DELETE-FILES}
    Run Keyword If    ${FILES}      Wait Until Page Contains And Click              ${OK}
    Run Keyword If    ${FILES}      Wait Until Page Does Not Contain Element        ${ANDROID-WIDGET-LISTVIEW}\[@resource-id="$FilesList"]
    Run Keyword If    ${FILES}      Wait Until Page Contains                        No Files
```

Comment: Show the html code of the elements that are suppose to be deleted

Comment: I'm not sure how to capture html. It's android. I capture the list layout locator which I observed when files listed then element list view visible. Then I capture the x delete button locator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very rough solution

```
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    999999
    YOUR TEST
    Exit For Loop If    CONDITION TO EXIT
END
```